# Solving the the Integral: $\int\frac{1}{u^2-2}du$

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms, substitution

I am attempting to solve the following integral, in which I am not sure, how to proceed:

$\int\frac{1}{u^2-2}du$

I have tried the following, but I am not sure if it is correct:

$y = u^2-2$

$dy = 2u*du$

$du = \frac{dy}{2u}$

Therefore:

$\int\frac{1}{u^2-1}du = \int\frac{1}{y}*\frac{dy}{2u} = \int\frac{1}{y}*\frac{1}{2u}dy = \int\frac{1}{y2u}dy$

Solving for u:

$u^2 = y+2$

$u = \sqrt{y + 2}$

Substituting $u$ for $\sqrt{y + 2}$:

$\int\frac{1}{y2u}dy = \int\frac{1}{y2(\sqrt{y + 2})}dy$

I am not sure, where to go from here. The only thing I can remember is to use the logarithm rule where:

$\int\frac{1}{y2(\sqrt{y + 2})}dy = ln|{y2(\sqrt{y + 2})}| + C$

Would that be correct?

Comment: Hint: $\dfrac{1}{u^2-k} = \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{k}} \cdot \left(\dfrac{1}{u-\sqrt{k}} - \dfrac{1}{u+\sqrt{k}}\right)$

Comment: and furthermore $\int \frac{1}{au+b}du = \frac 1 a \ln|au+b|+c$

Comment: An important takeaway here is that you don't want to mix variables like that when you do a substitution. Writing $dy=2u\cdot du$ is great, but don't solve it for $du$ by moving the $u$ over to the side with the $dy$. That's how you can make a mess out of an integral. If you can't make the substitution work without doing that, then you know it's the wrong substitution.

Comment: Thanks alot, very helpful.

Comment: I do not see any relation to functional analysis.

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int\frac{1}{u^2-2}du=\frac{1}{2\sqrt2}\int\left(\frac{1}{u-\sqrt2}-\frac{1}{u+\sqrt2}\right)du=\frac{1}{2\sqrt2}\ln\left|\frac{u-\sqrt2}{u+\sqrt2}\right|+C$$

Comment: How did you come about the $\frac{1}{2}$? Dou you think you can explain the process?

Comment: @Omari Celestine I fixed. See now please.

Comment: How did you come about the division in the logarithm in the final answer?

Comment: @Omari Celestine Because $\int\frac{1}{x}dx=\ln|x|+C$ and $\ln{a}-\ln{b}=\ln\frac{a}{b}$.

Comment: Definitely did not know that one. Thanks.

Comment: @Omari Celestine You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

Begin by the substitution $$u=\sqrt {2}v $$
the integral becomes

$$\int \frac {\sqrt {2}dv}{2 (v^2-1)}=\frac {1}{\sqrt {2}}\int\frac {dv}{v^2-1} $$

then use

$$\frac {1}{v^2-1}=\frac {1}{2}\Bigl (\frac {1 }{v-1}-\frac {1}{v+1}\Bigr) $$

Comment: I had a mistake with one of the values in the denominator. Could you please check it and let me know if it would be the same?

Comment: @OmariCelestinelook now .i edited a new one.

Comment: Where did the $v$ come from?

Comment: @OmariCelestine the new variable.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**:
$$
\frac{1}{u^2-2}=\frac{1}{(u-\sqrt2)(u+\sqrt2)}
$$
If you proceed with the scomposition for your algebraic fraction, you have:
$$
\frac{1}{(u-\sqrt2)(u+\sqrt2)}=\frac{A}{u-\sqrt2}+\frac{B}{u+\sqrt2}=\frac{A(u+\sqrt2)+B(u-\sqrt2)}{(u-\sqrt2)(u+\sqrt2)}
$$

You have that $A+B=0 \ $  AND $\ A-B=\sqrt2.\ $ So $A=\frac{\sqrt2}{2}$ and $B=- \frac{\sqrt2}{2}.$

Doing this, we come to the following integrals:
$$
\frac{\sqrt2}{2}\int\frac{\sqrt2}{u-\sqrt2}du - \frac{\sqrt2}{2}\int\frac{\sqrt2}{u+\sqrt2}du
$$
So, let's say the solutions..

Answer (score 1):

Another approach: Let $u=\sqrt2\sec t$, so $du=\sqrt2\sec t\tan t\,dt$. Then we have:

$$\begin{align}
\int\frac1{u^2-2}du &= \int\frac{\sqrt2\sec t\tan t}{2\sec^2t-2}dt\\
&= \frac1{\sqrt2}\int\frac{\sec t \tan t}{\sec^2 t-1}dt\\
&= \frac1{\sqrt2}\int\frac{\sec t\tan t}{\tan^2 t}dt\\
&= \frac1{\sqrt2}\int\frac{\sec t}{\tan t}dt\\
&= \frac1{\sqrt2}\int\csc t\,dt\\
&= -\frac1{\sqrt2}\ln\left|\csc t + \cot t\right|+C
\end{align}$$

Since $\sec t=\frac{u}{\sqrt2}$, we have $\csc t=\frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2-2}}$ and $\cot t=\frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt{u^2-2}}$. Thus, we end up with:

$$\begin{align}
-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\ln\left|\frac{u+\sqrt2}{\sqrt{u^2-2}}\right|+C &= -\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\ln\left|\sqrt{\frac{(u+\sqrt2)^2}{u^2-2}}\right|+C\\
&= -\frac{1}{2\sqrt2}\ln\left|\frac{(u+\sqrt2)^2}{(u+\sqrt2)(u-\sqrt2)}\right|+C\\
&= -\frac{1}{2\sqrt2}\ln\left|\frac{u+\sqrt2}{u-\sqrt2}\right|+C\\
&= \frac{1}{2\sqrt2}\ln\left|\frac{u-\sqrt2}{u+\sqrt2}\right|+C
\end{align}$$

Messy, but possibly instructive. Partial fractions are cleaner than trig substitution, when you can use them.

Answer (score 0):

An important method is the *decomposition in simple fractions*, which you can use when the integrand is the quotient of two polynomials and you can factor the denominator.

Here $u^2-2=(u-\sqrt2)(u+\sqrt2)$ and the decomposition is of the form

$$\frac a{u-\sqrt2}+\frac b{u+\sqrt2}=\frac{au+a\sqrt2+bu-\sqrt2b}{u^2-2}.$$

Then with $a=-b=\dfrac1{\sqrt8}$ we have the identity

$$\frac1{\sqrt8(u-\sqrt2)}-\frac1{\sqrt8(u+\sqrt2)}=\frac1{u^2-2}.$$

Then you finish with the well-known

$$\int\frac{du}{u+a}=\ln|u+a|.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\int\frac{du}{u^2-2}$$

Using trig substitution we have

$$u=\sqrt2 {\sec x}$$

$$du=\sqrt2 \sec x \tan x dx$$

$$\int \frac{\sqrt2 \sec x \tan x dx}{2\tan^2x}=\int \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\frac{dx}{\sin x}$$

$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\frac{dx}{\sin x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\int \csc x dx$$

$$-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \ln|\csc x + \cot x| + C$$

Now just substitute.